# HTML multi select opt group select box always scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have implemented HTML opt group select box.

After selecting a top element and scroll down, again when I am selecting an item which is located at the bottom of the select box.scroll position is automatically changing to top.this is not good in terms of usability.I spent lot of times to fix this issue.but still i couldnt.

https://jsfiddle.net/nsandaruwa/tj1f2gyx/5/

```js
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var originalScrollTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop();
  console.log(originalScrollTop);
  $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
  var self = this;
  $(this).parent().focus();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).parent().scrollTop(originalScrollTop);
  }, 0);

  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.select-checkbox option::before {
  content: "\2610";
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.select-checkbox option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" class="form-control select-checkbox" size="5">
  <optgroup label="One">
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Hippo</option>
    <option>Dinosaur</option>
    <option>Another Dog</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Two">
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Hippo</option>
    <option>Dinosaur</option>
    <option>Another Dog</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Three">
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Hippo</option>
    <option>Dinosaur</option>
    <option>Another Dog</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Please explain what the JavaScript portion of this is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @mplungjan after removing the line you mention.still, the issue is existing

Comment: Sou you add the code to allow multiple select without respecting the UI way of selecting multiple?

Comment: @mplungjan yes.current problem is first i select a option located in the top of the selectbox.after that i scroll down to the botton.and select a bottom item.then scroll position is automatically changing to top.this is annoying.current not preserving the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

Better?

```js
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const that = this;
  $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
  setTimeout(function() { that.scrollIntoView() },10)
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.select-checkbox option::before {
  content: "\2610";
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.select-checkbox option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" class="form-control select-checkbox" size="5">
  <optgroup label="One">
    <option>Dog 1</option>
    <option>Cat 1</option>
    <option>Hippo 1</option>
    <option>Dinosaur 1</option>
    <option>Another Dog 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Two">
    <option>Dog 2</option>
    <option>Cat 2</option>
    <option>Hippo 2</option>
    <option>Dinosaur 2</option>
    <option>Another Dog 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Three">
    <option>Dog 3</option>
    <option>Cat 3</option>
    <option>Hippo 3</option>
    <option>Dinosaur 3</option>
    <option>Another Dog 3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.after doing your change frame is re-centered after a selection.expected behaviour is that the frame isn't re-centered after a selection. Is this possible?